# How to identificate uav's roll and pitch model and control to track object?

Tags: control, uav

I'm building a drone distance controller for parrot mambo. I need to track a colored page with given distance and given heigth. I can get the yaw information from parrot mambo with 0.5 sec.

Since I have fixed size object that I need to track. I get pixel heigth from different distances and I fitted formula of $$y = A \dfrac{1}{x} + B$$ to find distance(x is distance of the object and y is pixel heigth of tracked object).
[image]
Than I take x positions of the object from different angles without changing the yaw of the drone and I fit a line to this data $$y = A x + B$$
[image]
To move the drone I'm using a library which called pyparrot. You can call a function fly_direct with arguments of roll, pitch, yaw, heigth and duration.

To identift transfer function of roll and pitch I set this duration to fixed time which is 0.1 sec. Than I gave 0.5 roll angle of parrot's max roll angle for 1 sec and I wait 10 sec to make the system stabilize. Than I gave -0.5 roll angle of parrot's max roll angle. Then I fit a first degree transfer function with no zero and product with 1/s since I fit the transfer function like step response $$\dfrac{K}{\tau s+1}\dfrac{1}{s}$$ $$ 4 \tau = settle time$$ .

After I done to identificate my system (pitch for ditance and roll for angle). I tested and I failed.

There are some problem of my progression. First I needed to linearize distance rather then $$y = A \dfrac{1}{x} + B$$

However my real problem is if I gave roll and pitch angle at the same time, they effect each other. I dont know whether they are coupled or I need to transform one of the control signal with the others transformation matrix.

Do you have any suggestion for me. What did I wrong? How can I identify system better? How to overcome coupling problem?

You can reference anything that I can learn to overcome my problem as well.

**UPDATE**

I linearize my distance function between 150cm - 400cm which seems to me linear. Then I identificate my system for pitch distance system again which result with

$$
G_z = \dfrac{0.01152 z + 0.0106}{z^2 + -1.779 z + 0.7788}
$$